# How to fix cgo error caused by race flag?

Tags: go, cgo

How can I fix this?

```
         STDERR: # runtime/cgo
gcc_libinit_windows.c: In function ‘_cgo_beginthread’:
gcc_libinit_windows.c:136:27: error: implicit declaration of function ‘_beginthread’; did you mean ‘_cgo_beginthread’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  136 |                 thandle = _beginthread(func, 0, arg);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                           _cgo_beginthread
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile:15: unit] Error 2
```

https://go.dev/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that it was some issue with cygwin compiler, after switching to mingw (https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

see the file go1.19.1\src\runtime\cgo\libcgo_windows.h

```
// Call _beginthread, aborting on failure.
void _cgo_beginthread(void (*func)(void*), void* arg);
```

so...

delete function `_cgo_beginthread` in `gcc_libinit_windows.c` will fix it